# how to push value to v-model on-click button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a looping data and I want to push/add/update the value to v-model `DataJournals.Description` when I click the button.

Here is what I tried.

**template**

```
<tr v-for="(DataJournals, index) in DataJournal" :key="DataJournals.value">
    <td>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="termsofdelivery" v-model="DataJournals.Description" rows="3" v-bind:disabled="DataJournals.SignSave == 1 ? true : false"></textarea>
    </td>
    <a href="javascript:;" v-on:click="greet(DataJournals.id, index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Speech</a>
</tr>
```

**My method**

```
greet: function (event, id, index) {
    this.DataJournal.Description = 'asddsaasddsaasddsa'
}
```

When I check `console.log` its working but not push to v-model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
greet: function (event, id, index) {
    this.DataJournal[index].Description = 'asddsaasddsaasddsa'
    this.DataJournal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.DataJournal))
}
```

In your html code

```
v-on:click="greet($event, DataJournals.id, index)"
```

You need to update reference to `this.DataJournal` to make component reactive.

Comment: i got this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Description' of undefined`

Comment: If you console.log(id, index) inside greet function, what do you get?

Comment: if i used `event` it show me `0 undefined` but if without it i get `5 0`

Comment: I updated the answer. If you need event, you need to pass as `v-on:click="greet($event, DataJournals.id, index)"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `index` to update data and it is better to render a link to inside td element

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    DataJournal: [
      {value:1, SignSave:1,id:1,Description:""},
      {value:2, SignSave:2,id:2,Description:""},
      {value:3, SignSave:3,id:3,Description:""},      
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   greet: function(id,index) {
    this.DataJournal[index].Description = "test";
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="(DataJournals, index) in DataJournal" :key="DataJournals.value">
    <td>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="termsofdelivery" v-model="DataJournals.Description" rows="3" v-bind:disabled="DataJournals.SignSave == 1 ? true : false"></textarea>
        <a href="javascript:;" v-on:click="greet(DataJournals.id, index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Speech</a>
    </td>
    
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```